# Perform task after model's DOM is displayed in view

Tags: angularjs

I have a code snippet in my content which is a model fetched from http. I am using syntax highlighter to prettify the code. So I need to call a javascript function as soon as the DOM is updated for that particular model.

Here is a sample code to make it clear. I am using alert to demonstrate it. In my project I would use a third party plugin which will find matching dom elements and remodel them. 
Here, 
I want the alert to occur after the list is displayed

**jsfiddle :**
http://jsfiddle.net/7xZde/2/

My controller has something like this.

```
$scope.items = Model.notes();
alert('test');
```

alert comes even before the items list is shown, I want it after the list is displayed.

Any hint to help me achieve this.

Comment: Updated. Sorry. I felt it was silly doubt so didn't feel like adding much detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use $timeout ,

```
$scope.items = Model.notes();
$timeout(function () {
    alert('test');
})
```

Yeah it was silly , $timeout seemed to be a misnomer to me. I am 2 days old to angularjs . Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

Lucky for you, I wanted to do the exact same thing. Mutation observers are the path forward, but if you need backwards compatibility with older browsers, you'll need a bit more code than this.

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xXD6P1?p=preview) for Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
})

.directive('watchChanges', function ($parse, $timeout) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var setter = $parse(attrs.watchChanges).assign;

        // create an observer instance
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    var text = angular.element('<div></div>').text(element.html()).text();
                    setter(scope, text);
                });
            });
        });

        // configuration of the observer:
        var config = {
            attributes: true,
            childList: true,
            characterData: true,
            subtree: true
        };

        // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
        observer.observe(element[0], config);
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div watch-changes="text">
      <p>Hello {{ name }}</p>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
    </div>
    <pre>{{text}}</pre>
  </body>
```

Comment: can you please look at my question again, I updated it with an example. Its sillier than what you interpreted . Thankyou for your effort.